# group_by two parametrs

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In the tasks_controller, I defined:

```
def index
    @tasks = Task.all

    respond_to do |format|
       format.html # index.html.erb
       format.json { render json: @tasks }
    end
end
```

I have three parameters in my table: name, task, done.

now, I want to produce:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>num of tasks</th>
        <th>num tasks left</th>
    </tr>

    <% @tasks.group_by(&:name).each do |name, tasks| %>
        <tr>
            <td><%= name %></td>
            <td><%= tasks.size %></td>
            <td> here I want to produce the number of tasks left </td>
        </tr>
    <% end %>
</table>
```

**how can I get the number of tasks left? I think it should be something like:**

```
        <% @tasks.group_by(&:name).each do |name, tasks| %>
             <tr>
                <td><%= name %></td>
                <td><%= tasks.size %></td>
                <% @tasks.group_by(name, :done => "yes").each do |name, tasks| %>
                     <td><%= tasks.size %></td>
                <% end %>
             </tr> 
         <% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had a good idea ;)

```
<% @tasks.group_by(&:name).each do |name, tasks| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= name %></td>
    <td><%= tasks.size %></td>
    <td><%= tasks.select{ |task| task.done != 'yes' }.size %></td>
  </tr> 
<% end %>
```

`tasks.select{ |task| task.done != 'yes' }` : This will select the tasks where done is not yes, put it in an array and calculate its size (number of tasks not done yet).

I strongly recommend you to set your @tasks variable like following (takes much less performances: the DB does the work for you!)

```
# in the controller
@tasks = Task.count(:group => 'name') #instead of @tasks = Task.all
```

It has the same output as `@tasks.group_by(...)` but is much better in execution time.

Comment: I updated my answer with a tip @AlonShmiel take a look at it ;)